# reformat items in lists into different types and sublists

Tags: python, list, loops, types

```
UNCLEANED = [
['1 -  32/', 'Highway', '403', '43.167233',
 '-80.275567', '1965', '2014', '2009', '4',
 'Total=64  (1)=12;(2)=19;(3)=21;(4)=12;', '65', '04/13/2012', '72.3', '',
 '72.3', '', '69.5', '', '70', '', '70.3', '', '70.5', '', '70.7', '72.9',
 ''],
['1 -  43/', 'WEST', '403', '43.164531', '-80.251582',
 '1963', '2014', '2007', '4',
 'Total=60.4  (1)=12.2;(2)=18;(3)=18;(4)=12.2;', '61', '04/13/2012',
 '71.5', '', '71.5', '', '68.1', '', '69', '', '69.4', '', '69.4', '',
 '70.3', '73.3', ''],
['2 -   4/', 'STOKES', '6', '45.036739', '-81.33579', '1958',
 '2013', '', '1', 'Total=16  (1)=16;', '18.4', '08/28/2013', '85.1',
 '85.1', '', '67.8', '', '67.4', '', '69.2', '70', '70.5', '', '75.1', '',
 '90.1', '']
]
```

above is an un cleaned version of a list containing three sublists... 
and I need to transform it into a more cleaner version that may look alike this:

```
CLEANED = [[1, 'Highway', '403', 43.167233,
              -80.275567, '1965', '2014', '2009', 4,
              [12.0, 19.0, 21.0, 12.0], 65.0, '04/13/2012',
              [72.3, 69.5, 70.0, 70.3, 70.5, 70.7, 72.9]],
             [2, 'WEST', '403', 43.164531, -80.251582,
              '1963', '2014', '2007', 4, [12.2, 18.0, 18.0, 12.2], 61.0, 
              '04/13/2012', [71.5, 68.1, 69.0, 69.4, 69.4, 70.3,
                             73.3]],
             [3, 'STOKES', '6', 45.036739, -81.33579, '1958',
              '2013', '', 1, [16.0], 18.4, '08/28/2013',
              [85.1, 67.8, 67.4, 69.2, 70.0, 70.5, 75.1, 90.1]]
            ]
```

and I figured that the pattern is for index[0] in the uncleaned version, I keep only the first character. `index[1]` , `[2]` keep the same, turn `index[3]` and `[4]` into int.....

then reach `index[9]`, I have to ignore the total, and extract only the rest of the numbers then put into a sublist.....

the last thing is to put the numbers after the date into a sublist and also excluding the first number.

I am very confused on how to continually loop this until it finishes "cleaning" everything in the **UNCLEANED**?

And what if the **UNCLEANED** isn't just those three elements? if it was very long, how would I loop through it?

Thank you very much for your help

Comment: You have multiple very arbitrary rules that has to be created manually - you should give it a try first. If you're not sure how to loop, try `for list in list_of_list: ...`

Comment: The first item of the last list in `CLEANED`  is an `int` 3 yet the first item of the last list of `UNCLEANED` is a `str` with the first character `'2'`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution that does the conversion described above. It's a simple `for` loop:

```
UNCLEANED = [
['1 -  32/', 'Highway', '403', '43.167233',
 '-80.275567', '1965', '2014', '2009', '4',
 'Total=64  (1)=12;(2)=19;(3)=21;(4)=12;', '65', '04/13/2012', '72.3', '',
 '72.3', '', '69.5', '', '70', '', '70.3', '', '70.5', '', '70.7', '72.9',
 ''],
['1 -  43/', 'WEST', '403', '43.164531', '-80.251582',
 '1963', '2014', '2007', '4',
 'Total=60.4  (1)=12.2;(2)=18;(3)=18;(4)=12.2;', '61', '04/13/2012',
 '71.5', '', '71.5', '', '68.1', '', '69', '', '69.4', '', '69.4', '',
 '70.3', '73.3', ''],
['2 -   4/', 'STOKES', '6', '45.036739', '-81.33579', '1958',
 '2013', '', '1', 'Total=16  (1)=16;', '18.4', '08/28/2013', '85.1',
 '85.1', '', '67.8', '', '67.4', '', '69.2', '70', '70.5', '', '75.1', '',
 '90.1', '']
]

# Function that performs the conversion described above.
def cleanElement(elem):
    elem[0] = elem[0].split(' - ')[0]
    elem[3] = float(elem[3])
    elem[4] = float(elem[4])

    elem[8] = int(elem[8])

    tempList = elem[9].split('  ')[1].split(';')
    tempList = [float(i.split('=')[1]) for i in tempList if not i=='']
    elem[9] = tempList

    elem[10] = float(elem[10])

    elem[13] = [float(i) for i in elem[13:] if not i=='']
    elem.pop(12)

    return elem[:13]

# Function that loops in the uncleaned list and performs the conversion for each element.
def cleanList(uncleaned):
    return [cleanElement(elem) for elem in uncleaned]

cleaned = cleanList(UNCLEANED)

for i in cleaned:
    print(i)
```

Output:

```
['1', 'Highway', '403', 43.167233, -80.275567, '1965', '2014', '2009', 4, [12.0, 19.0, 21.0, 12.0], 65.0, '04/13/2012', [72.3, 69.5, 70.0, 70.3, 70.5, 70.7, 72.9]]
['1', 'WEST', '403', 43.164531, -80.251582, '1963', '2014', '2007', 4, [12.2, 18.0, 18.0, 12.2], 61.0, '04/13/2012', [71.5, 68.1, 69.0, 69.4, 69.4, 70.3, 73.3]]
['2', 'STOKES', '6', 45.036739, -81.33579, '1958', '2013', '', 1, [16.0], 18.4, '08/28/2013', [85.1, 67.8, 67.4, 69.2, 70.0, 70.5, 75.1, 90.1]]
```

Comment: Hi ! Thank you so much for your answer, however, the program keeps telling me 
`builtins.AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'split'`  . and since I need to convert those into under one function instead of creating new functions, so I am quite confused, how would I do that in one function.. Thank you!!!

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Would you like to elaborate more on the problem, because running it as it is does not throw any errors for me. Which line throws this error?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative way to clean up the list of lists using a collection of functions.

The tricky part was accounting for the slicing of the last part of the list where there are alternating strings that have to be gathered into an array and filtered for empty strings.

I assumed that the non-empty string value in the first 3 items of the tail part of each subarray was the desired value. `arrange` handles putting the first 3 items in an order that returns a consistent value.

IMHO, the advantage of this way is that if you want to do anything different with any particular item, it can be easier to change the code.

```
import itertools as it

def get_first_char_int(item):
    first_char, *_ = item
    return int(first_char)

def identity(item):
    return item

def get_floats(item):
    tokens = ''.join(item.split(' ')[2:]).split('=')[1:]
    return [float(token.split(';')[0]) for token in tokens]

def get_float(item):
    return float(item) if item else item

UNCLEANED = [
    ['1 -  32/', 'Highway', '403', '43.167233',
     '-80.275567', '1965', '2014', '2009', '4',
     'Total=64  (1)=12;(2)=19;(3)=21;(4)=12;', '65', '04/13/2012', '72.3', '',
     '72.3', '', '69.5', '', '70', '', '70.3', '', '70.5', '', '70.7', '72.9',
     ''],
    ['1 -  43/', 'WEST', '403', '43.164531', '-80.251582',
     '1963', '2014', '2007', '4',
     'Total=60.4  (1)=12.2;(2)=18;(3)=18;(4)=12.2;', '61', '04/13/2012',
     '71.5', '', '71.5', '', '68.1', '', '69', '', '69.4', '', '69.4', '',
     '70.3', '73.3', ''],
    ['2 -   4/', 'STOKES', '6', '45.036739', '-81.33579', '1958',
     '2013', '', '1', 'Total=16  (1)=16;', '18.4', '08/28/2013', '85.1',
     '85.1', '', '67.8', '', '67.4', '', '69.2', '70', '70.5', '', '75.1', '',
     '90.1', ''],
]

functions = [ # 1:1 mapping of functions to items in each list in UNCLEANED.
    get_first_char_int,
    identity,
    identity,
    float,
    float,
    identity,
    identity,
    identity,
    int,
    get_floats,
    float,
    identity,
]
end = len(functions)
item_length, = {len(items) for items in UNCLEANED}
# Calculate argument to pass to it.islice
extra_count = item_length - end
# Extend functions by extra_count times with get_float
functions.extend(list(it.repeat(get_float, extra_count)))
#
# Handle items up to start of alternating strings and empty strings.
head_results = (
    [f(item)
     for f, item
     in zip(functions[0:end], collection[0:end])]
    for collection in UNCLEANED
)

def arrange(items):
    """Handle varying order of first 3 items of items."""
    item, *_ = items
    items[0:3] = [item, '', item]
    return items
#
# Apply arrange to the tail of each sublist
collection_ = it.chain.from_iterable(arrange(collection[end:])
                                     for collection in UNCLEANED)
#
# Handle items starting with alternating strings and empty strings.
tail_results = (
    [f(item)
     for f, item
     in it.islice(zip(functions[end:], collection_), 2, item_length)]
    for collection in UNCLEANED
)

results = [[head, [item for item in tail if item]]
            for head, tail in zip(head_results, tail_results)]

for item in results:
    print(item)
```

Output:

```
[[1, 'Highway', '403', 43.167233, -80.275567, '1965', '2014', '2009', 4, [12.0, 19.0, 21.0, 12.0], 65.0, '04/13/2012'], [72.3, 69.5, 70.0, 70.3, 70.5, 70.7, 72.9]]
[[1, 'WEST', '403', 43.164531, -80.251582, '1963', '2014', '2007', 4, [12.2, 18.0, 18.0, 12.2], 61.0, '04/13/2012'], [71.5, 68.1, 69.0, 69.4, 69.4, 70.3, 73.3]]
[[2, 'STOKES', '6', 45.036739, -81.33579, '1958', '2013', '', 1, [16.0], 18.4, '08/28/2013'], [85.1, 67.8, 67.4, 69.2, 70.0, 70.5, 75.1, 90.1]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a clean_row(row) function, then all the "clean rules" should be called from here. Then you can do `CLEANED = [clean_row(uncleaned) for uncleaned in UNCLEANED]`.